# Getting 503 errors from Amazon S3 behind CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a strange issue regarding a S3 bucket.
Starting a couple of weeks ago I started to receive a lot of 503 requests.
Although I have a Cloudfront distribution in front of the bucket there are a couple of requests that are made directly on S3.
Based on the fact that S3 is limited to 3,500 PUT/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET requests per second, I have started to inspect the log files for this bucket and it seems that I do not exceed ~300 requests/second of all summed requests, during the interval when I start to receive 503 errors. So basically I my requests rate per second does not exceed 3500 write or 5500 read requests.

Besides Cloudfront I use a couple of EC2 instances, and some Lambda functions for operations on the objects.

I can not understand why this happens.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Need more details. Besides CF, are other aws services accessing the objects at the same time?

Comment: @jellycsc, thank you for your reply. Yes, besides CF I have a couple of EC2 instances and some Lambda functions that are making requests on the objects. I can see those requests in the log files but including those requests I don't exceed ~300 requests/second.

Comment: You typically want the request rate on the individual S3 prefixes to increase gradually.

Comment: Basically I have this structure. With a lot of requests on the following paths. You are saying that it's ok for S3 to respond to my request with 503 Slow Down.
Meanwhile AWS will increase my request rate?

/collections/items/random-hash
/collections/json/random-hash
/collections/uploads/random-hash

If yes, which is the actual request rate and how can I prevent 503 Slow Down.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update regarding my situation.
After spending a couple of days with AWS Premium Suport they found an internal issue in the S3.
My actual rate request was well bellow their limited request rate. The internal process that was causing the throttling is related to the S3 lifecycle rule that I have in place for transitioning some old objects to IA storage class, deleting previous versions of an object older than 90 days, deleting the objects with the delete marker and delete incomplete multipart uploads after 7 days.

A quick fix to my situation was made by the S3 Service Team by manually partitioning the files across multiple partitions and at my suggestion temporarily disable the lifecycle rule to mitigate any 503 issues until a permanent fix is applied. They are working on a fix for this issue.